# In Tradingview strategy alerts, what are syntax for take profit and stop loss?

Tags: tradingview-api

If i use a tradingview strategy and put alert on it so that it sends that alert to a webhook, a placeholder "strategy.order.action — returns the string “buy” or “sell” for the executed order.". But what will it return in case of take profit or stop loss? How can I configure it in my Python code to automate. If there is a "buy" signal, we will close old short order and create a long order, but what if it hits take profit.